# set property of js module with nested callback

Tags: javascript, module, scope, callback

Im trying to set a modules variable/property from a nested function (basically a xhr callback (`Api.get()`) inside that module (in the `init()` function), but it does not work and I can not figure out why.

```
    //posts
    var Posts = (function() {
            //array of all posts objects
        var data = null;

        //initialize the posts module
        var init = function(callback) {

            if(data === null) {
                //load all posts
                loadAll(function(response){
                    // data = JSON.parse(response)

                    var posts = JSON.parse(response)
                    //create array
                    data = posts;
                    // call callback
                    console.log(data)
                    callback()

                })
            }
        }
        // return all posts from api as json
        var loadAll = function(callback) {
            Api.get('/api/posts/get', function(response) {
                callback(response)
            })
        }


        //public interface
        return {
            data: data,
            init: init,
            loadAll: loadAll
        }
    })();
```

After calling `Posts.init()` I log `Posts.data` to the console, but it is still `null`. However, `console.log(data)` inside the `init()` method logs the expected array of objects im trying to assign to `Posts.data`. It seems that `data` inside the callback is another variable than `Posts.data`. Can someone please explain why and if possible, provide a solution for setting the modules `data` property inside `Api.get()`?

Comment: The object you are returning has a data property that points to `null`. Changing the the `data` variable later, doesn't change the value in the returned object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a reference to the return object so you can alter its `data` property after you've returned the object. One way to do this would be to create an object with the methods and data and return that object. Then you can refer to its `data` property internally with `this.data`:

```js
// Fake API
let Api = {
  get(url, cb) {
    cb('["testdata"]')
  }
}

//posts
var Posts = (function() {
  //array of all posts objects
  return {
    data: null,
    init(callback) {
      if (this.data === null) {
        //load all posts
        this.loadAll((response) => {       // arrow function needed here for correct `this` binding
          var posts = JSON.parse(response)

          //create array
          this.data = posts;  // add data
          callback()
        })
      }
    },
    loadAll(callback) {
      Api.get('/api/posts/get', function(response) {
        callback(response)
      })
    }
  }
})();

console.log("initial posts data: ", Posts.data)
Posts.init(() => console.log("After init():", Posts.data))
```

If you do it this way, you don't actually need the IEFE unless you plan on making multiple objects. You can just use `Posts = {/* rest of the data and methods */}`. This would also work well as a class instead of a plain object.